# webpage forward to itself by Java Servlet doesn't act correct on browser back/forward button

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I try to design a discussion forum but it seems to have a little problem. For my example, structure of my forum is topicsPage.jsp contains a bunch of topics, and replyPage.jsp contains a bunch of replies and a textArea allows people to reply to that topic. and now I got a problem, if an user posted a reply, and he want to go back to the topicPage.jsp, he clicked browser's back button, the browser didn't go to topicsPage.jsp, instead of doing that, the browser still stay at replyPage.jsp with the state which before user submit his reply.

I believe this is not the only situation will cause this problem, any situation which needs servlet to forward to the original webpage will having this problem. is there any ways to solve this problem?

Comment: try using a single page application, and do the loading using ajax (e.g. jquery).

Answer (score 1):

My Suggestion is better to go with monitoring the session in your jsp which looks some thing like this

```
if (session == null || session.getAttribute("username") == null) {
        response.sendRedirect("yourDesiredpage.jsp"); // No logged-in user found, so redirect to login page.
    } else {
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);  
    }
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, you should always do a redirect and not a forward after a submit (`post`).  It avoids a lot of problems with the back button of the browser. That is called the [post - redirect - pattern](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)