# Java Servlet Need Browser Back Button to Resubmit Request

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

So here is my situation.

I have jsp A that does a query and displays data. On jsp A I have a form which will POST to a new servlet, the action on the form is "/data" or too the servlet directly. The doPost method will forward the request to a new jsp (jsp B) I am working on. This jsp B allows the user to select a second data point and, on submit, will forward two data sets back to jsp B where the data sets are presented side by side for comparison.

Now jsp B allows the user to drill down several layers of increasing detail. Each drill down makes a new POST back to the servlet which, in turn, forwards the new data back to jsp B. Again, the form on jsp B has an action of "/data", the servlet itself.

So goes to jsp B does a comparison and drills down two levels. Now the user wants to go back up on level. If the user clicks the browser "Back" button, the browser displays an error. A refresh of the page then displays the proper level of data.

I want the back button to automatically go back a level, resubmitting the form if necessary, and displaying the proper data.

In researching this, I found mentions of Post/Redirect/Get patterns. I also found [this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26134542/4215616) indicating that once a post is made that redirect should be used in lieu of forward.

How do I achieve the desired result without forcing the user to a) start the comparison over, and b) not have to hit refresh after the the back button.

Thank you

Comment: Try using Ajax.

Comment: @11thdimension I thought of that. Making the action the jsp name and then using ajax calls to retrieve and display the data. I will go that route if there are no other viable suggestions. Thank you for the input. I do value the contribution